# Select columns from CassandraRow in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

How to select columns from CassandraRow dynamically. the columns are not fixed. example code below.

```
var columnList = "column1, column2, column3" // this is generated dynamically 
SparkContextFunctions(sc)
  .cassandraTable(ckeyspaceName, tableName)
  .select(columnList)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example like this:

```
val columns = Seq("column1", "column2", "column3").map(ColumnName(_))
val table = SparkContextFunctions(sc).cassandraTable(ckeyspaceName, tableName)
table.select(columns: _*)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How to convert a String to Seq. For example, I have 

      **var columnList = "column1, column2, column3"** 

How to convert it to Seq?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I change it to a **val columnList: List[String]**, then **val columns = columnList.map(ColumnName(_))**. and it works.